# Linker Error - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors

This error happens when I try to import the file "VARendererViewController.h" from the file "VAMenuScreenViewController"

```
duplicate symbol _gestureMinimumTranslation in:
/Users/Sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Virtual_Human_Avatar-fwgdkxpnkzapxrdzkggtmbnfhjwb/Build/Intermediates/Virtual Human Avatar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Virtual Human Avatar.build/Objects-normal/i386/VARendererViewController.o
/Users/Sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Virtual_Human_Avatar-fwgdkxpnkzapxrdzkggtmbnfhjwb/Build/Intermediates/Virtual Human Avatar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Virtual Human Avatar.build/Objects-normal/i386/VAMenuScreenViewController.o
```

ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could anyone provide me with some

Comment: How is gestureMinimumTranslation declared?  It sounds like you've got the constant just defined in the header, but it should be declared "extern" in the header and defined in a source file.

Answer (score 4):

You have two compilation units -- two source files -- that are defining the same symbol.

This may be because you defined the symbol in two separate .m files (or other compilation unit; .c, .mm, etc...) or because you defined the symbol in a header file and imported it into those two files.   Alternatively, if you shove a variable declaration into a header file without the `extern`, then it'll cause a symbol by that name to be created in every `.m` file it is imported into.

Assuming `gestureMinimumTranslation` is a variable, then if you really want a global variable, it should be defined in *only one .m file* as follows:

```
int gestureMinimumTranslation;
```

Then, in the corresponding header:

```
extern int gestureMinimumTranslation;
```

And the *other* `.m` file should import the above header.

Answer (score 0):

The linker is trying to join a set of objects with a common symbol. This often happens when the `Compile  Sources` `Build Phase` has duplicate entries or a header file. Try removing these.

Comment: If that were the case, the error would be different.   This looks to be a straightforward duplicate symbol declaration across two implementation files.